# how can i click twice on the icon of tabview (home ) to get me to the to the parent view

Tags: swift, swiftui, tabview

i have a lot of navigation link inside the homeview when i click to other icon of tabview and go back  to homeview it show me the last view that i leave so i want to add something like click two times on icon home view to see the first view of tabview  and this is my code on content view :

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection = 3
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection:$selection){
            
            Text("hello")
                .tabItem{
                    Image("profile (2)").renderingMode(.template)
                    Text("Profile")
                }.tag(1)
            

            Text("hello")
                .tabItem{
                    Image("search (1)").renderingMode(.template)
                    Text("Search")
                }.tag(2)
            HomeView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image("home").renderingMode(.template)
                    Text("Home")
                }.tag(3)
                
            SettingsView()
                .tabItem{
                    Image("Layer 5").renderingMode(.template)
                    Text("Settings")
                    
                }.tag(4)
           
            Text("hello")
                .tabItem{
                    Image("message (1)").renderingMode(.template)
                    Text("Message")
                }.tag(5)
            
        }.accentColor(.purple)
         
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60691250/12299030 or this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/65048085/12299030?

Comment: no maybe  the second one  but stackoverflow.com/a/65048085/12299030 just in one click send u to the first view and my goal is one click to see your last view and two click to restart with the parent view